# Ranking of different Result Sources within one web part in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've one result source that having 5 different different content source.
For example:People,Doctor,Citrix,ServiceNow,State.
Now on the page I'm using this result source to bind my web part. Here I want to display first people results then servicenow,citrix,docor and then state content source results.

requesting anyone help me find out which ranking model should i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query rule to change the order in which search results are displayed.

1. Create a query rule on the result source.
2. As you do not need the query rule to be triggered by a specific condition, click **Remove Condition** to remove conditions for this rule.
3. Click on **Change ranked results by changing the query** and open the **Sorting** tab in the **Build Your Query dialog**.
4. Select **Rank** in the **Sort by** drop down and add dynamic ordering rule in **Dynamic ordering** section. Enter your condition and set the order as you want.

A demo about [how to change the order in which search results are displayed in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794217.aspx).